# Zip then encrypt multiple files into a single archive

Tags: c#, encryption, zip, compression, aes

As per the title I am wanting to take multiple files, zip them up and encrypt them using AES256 in to a single archive in a single pass. **Is this possible?**

I have managed to achieve a single file in to a single archive using the following code:

```
internal static void Encrypt(string filePath, string zipPath, byte[] key)
{
    // Create the streams used for encryption.
    using (var outputStream = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.KeySize = 256;

            aes.Key = key;
            aes.GenerateIV();

            // Write the IV in to the start of the file first.
            outputStream.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);

            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(outputStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (DeflateStream zip = new DeflateStream(csEncrypt, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

                    using (var dataStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        int bytesRead = dataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        // Read the data in to a buffer to limit memory usage.
                        while (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            zip.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                            bytesRead = dataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Flush after DeflateStream is disposed.
                csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have then tried to take this further using `ZipArchive` to include multiple files using the following:

```
internal static void EncryptArchive(string filePath, string zipPath, byte[] key)
{
    // Create the streams used for encryption.
    using (var outputStream = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.KeySize = 256;

            aes.Key = key;
            aes.GenerateIV();

            // Write the IV in to the start of the file first.
            outputStream.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);

            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(outputStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (var zip = new ZipArchive(csEncrypt, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

                    var entry = zip.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(filePath));

                    using (var dataStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                    {
                        int bytesRead = dataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        // Read the data in to a buffer to limit memory usage.
                        while (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            entryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                            bytesRead = dataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Flush after DeflateStream is disposed.
                csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now although the method is not set up to handle multiple files yet it currently can't even handle 1. As soon as I try to write to *entryStream* an exception is thrown stating that the stream does not support `CanSeek`.

I assume ZIPs need to support seeking in order to store whatever positional metadata available for applications like Explorer to display their contents. This requirement does not fit in to our use case so I am happy to workaround it if needed.

I have looked in to other libraries however [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) seems to have some rather bad reviews more recently and not a lot of activity on it. [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) does support AES 256 but looking at the source code it is built around using ECB which we all know is pretty much useless. This has currently left me believing that my only choice may be to write the multiple files in to the zip along with some metadata that identifies where in the stream they are positioned (I obviously won't be able to `Seek` to find these but that is not an issue).

**To hopefully help clarify what I want to achieve:**

I have multiple files (A, B, C), I want to create a zip archive (D) and then encrypt it in the same pass (De). All this should be done **without** storing D on disk. I am currently using `FileStream`s as a test, it is most likely that these will be `MemoryStream`s later on to prevent unencrypted data touching the file system.

Have I missed anything? Is this possible?

Comment: So, you have multiple files (A, B, C) and you want to deflate each one (a, b, c) and then encrypt each one (ae, be, ce) and then put all three into a single archive (D)?

Comment: @Forty3 No Sorry I have multiple files (A, B, C), I want to create a zip archive (D) and then encrypt it in the same pass (De). All this should be done without storing D on disk. I am currently using FileStreams as a test, it is most likely that these will be MemoryStreams later on to prevent unencrypted data touching the file system.

Comment: It sounds like your analysis is correct. I think the problem is that zip creation/modification is not stream compatible, in other words adding a file to a zip archive does not simply cause data to be appended to the existing zip archive. Theoretically, given that you have a priori all the files and their lengths, it could be *possible* to design a zip library that supports your use case. However I doubt any of the existing libraries does. Ready to write your own?

Comment: Note that *compression* is streamable, and you could create your own compressed archive format that is also streamable and has none of the bells and whistles that the zip format has.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I was afraid someone would confirm what you have just said. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide an answer I have in fact gone with @JamesKPolks suggestion of writing my own library to do the zipping and encryption of multiple files.

I am not at liberty to provide the actual code based solution plus it has been built tailored to our specific needs so might not be the most useful to others. However in short the following approach was taken.

The file is split into 2 main parts:

**1. Plaintext**

IV

**2. Encrypted**

This is then split in to 2 parts:

*2.1. Metadata*

Names of the entries to be stored, padded at the end to aid the reading based on fixed block sizes.

*2.2. Contents*

The data entries themselves marked at the start by a hash of the name entry in 2.1 Metadata. The contents are also written in a fixed block size with padding.

**Summary**

The resulting library has been fairly trivial to write, however it has taken a fair amount of thought upfront. That being said there is still a little bit left to finish off with allowing streaming out of the archive.

I would hope to have released the code but I am not at liberty at present. Should anyone need assistance with a similar task I would be more than happy to offer help.

Comment: I am very interested in this. Can you give me a few pointers on your process? What was your thought process?

Comment: @jkw4703 the reason to implement such a thing was down to the fact that an existing client-server communication mechanism used password protected zips to transfer large chunks of data between them. Unfortunately these fail to meet the minimum level of encryption that is required so we moved to find a solution that would cause the least amount of risk when being replaced. Next we just had to work around our limitations mainly not being able to `Seek` in a `CryptoStream`. I believe we are pretty much matching ZIP file structure while maintaining the security level we need. Does that help?